# How to compute the variance for repeated measurements with clustered observations?

Tags: mixed-model, experiment-design, clustered-standard-errors

I have some data that looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'user_id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
  'experiment_group': ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
  'metric_value': [10, 5, 8, 7, 10, 11, 9, 8, 5, 8, 9]
})
```

As you can see:

- User 1 has 4 treatment exposures and 2 control.
- User 2 has 2 control exposures and 3 treatments.

I'm trying to recreate the output of the following OLS model:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
m = smf.ols("metric_value ~ experiment_group", df).fit(cov_type='cluster', cov_kwds={'groups': df['user_id']})
pd.DataFrame({
  'params': m.params,
  'SE': m.bse
})
```

I'm able to compute the weighted difference in means and match the coefficient, but it is not clear how would I compute the standard error in this case.

```
# Group by user and experiment group to get sum of metric values and count of observations
grouped = df.groupby(['user_id', 'experiment_group']).metric_value.agg(['sum', 'count']).unstack()
# Compute the weighted mean for each user
grouped['mean_T'] = grouped[('sum', 'T')] / grouped[('count', 'T')]
grouped['mean_C'] = grouped[('sum', 'C')] / grouped[('count', 'C')]
grouped['weight_treatment'] = ((grouped['count']['T']) * len(grouped)) / grouped['count']['T'].sum()
grouped['weight_control'] = ((grouped['count']['C']) * len(grouped)) / grouped['count']['C'].sum()
grouped['diff_weighted'] = grouped['mean_T'] * grouped['weight_treatment'] - grouped['mean_C'] * grouped['weight_control']
grouped['diff_weighted'].mean()
```

Any suggestions for what needs to be done to calculate the a weighted standard error correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have 2 or more categorical factors, then in the unbalanced case the group means are not the same as the OLS estimated coefficients because group effects are only orthogonal in the balanced case (all cell counts equal). It's easier just to use OLS, and then compute the sandwich from there.

Answer (score 4):

It is not going to be as easy as reproducing the parameter estimates, you're looking at a few matrix multiplications at least. I'm not familiar with Python for statistics, but a quick glance at the documentation shows that you're fitting a clustered sandwich variance estimator. The original paper describing these is [this one](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/jbes.2010.07136) (edit: turns out this is the *multiway* clustering paper, but it references the one-way methods as well).

The same method is implemented in the R package `sandwich`, the documentation of its clustered covariance estimator is available for example [here](https://sandwich.r-forge.r-project.org/reference/vcovCL.html). That link leads to more details on the mathematics behind the sandwich estimator, such as [this overview paper](https://sandwich.r-forge.r-project.org/articles/pdf/sandwich.pdf).

The first few steps will be to recreate the estimating functions, for an OLS this is the residuals multiplied by the design matrix, and sum those within clusters. Add the resulting matrix to its own cross product divided by the total number of observations. The default in both R and Python seems to be the so-called HC1 estimator, which includes additional Bessel corrections as well. The final result here is the 'meat' matrix. The 'bread' is created from the original non-robust covariance matrix scaled by the total degrees of freedom. The 'sandwich' is the matrix multiplication of bread * meat * bread, and the standard errors are the square roots of its diagonal elements.

I could paste some more formulas here which I'd only understand superficially myself, or parts of the [R source code](https://github.com/cran/sandwich/blob/master/R/vcovCL.R) (or perhaps the `statsmodels` source?), but I'm not sure if that'd be of much more help.